# How can i set text to text view in the base adapter?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android ,write this simple adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, String[] prgmImages) {   
        //Do something... and dont write this code
    }
    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Want write this code>>>>TextView1.SetText("Hello");

    }

}
```

and call up adapter in main activity with this line:

```
 lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myLIST);
                lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));
```

I want when custom adepter call and process some thing,write result into the main activity text view.how can i do this?thanks.

Comment: You can use interface as callback to the activity.

Comment: @Raghunandan how can i use that?

Comment: Posted an answer look at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, It is one method, you can find different methods also.

create a function in `Activity` class

```
public void refreshData(){
    //CODE TO SET TEXT
}
```

And call the function from adapter using the context.

Eg: in Adapter class, call like this.

```
((MainActivity)context).refreshData();
```

You can also use interface, but, in this case, no need to use that, using `context` is fine for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have a interface

```
public interface EventListener
{
   public void onEvent(String result);
}
```

Then in Constructor

```
 EventListener eventListener; 
 public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, String[] prgmImages) {   
    //Do something... and dont write this code
    eventListener = (EventListener) mainActivity;
}
```

In `getView`

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     evenListener.onEvent("Hello");

}
```

Then in Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements EventListener
```

Then

```
@Override
public void onEvent(String result)
{
    // do something. set text to textview here
}
```